# How can I use React Hooks with ReactJS.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, react-hooks, es6-modules, server-side-rendering, reactjs.net

We are currently migrating our frontend from jQuery to Reactjs.NET. We are using React 16.8 which allows us to use React Hooks instead of classes.

We setup our project successfully and tried it first with classes and server side rendering which worked well, but my team rather use React Hooks. I tried using Webpack + Babel to transpile .jsx files since it didn't work anymore using only razor helper `@Html.React()`, but I still get the same error from my component.

We are using Asp.NET 4.x and NET framework 4.7.

This is my view children.cshtml

```
@Html.React("ChildrenForm", new {
   familyTiesId = Model.FamilyTiesId 
   },
   serverOnly:true
)
```

This is my ReactConfig.cs:

```
namespace Nop.Web
{
    public static class ReactConfig
    {
        public static void Configure()
        {
            // If you want to use server-side rendering of React components, 
            // add all the necessary JavaScript files here. This includes 
            // your components as well as all of their dependencies.
            // See http://reactjs.net/ for more information. Example:
            ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration
                .AddScript("~/Scripts/Components/Customer/ChildrenForm.jsx");

            JsEngineSwitcher.Current.DefaultEngineName = V8JsEngine.EngineName;
            JsEngineSwitcher.Current.EngineFactories.AddV8();
        }
    }
}
```

My component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const ChildrenForm = (props) => {

    const [ familyTiesId, setFamilyTiesId ] = useState(props.familyTiesId);

...
}
```

It should work, but instead I get:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Line 20:         @Html.React("ChildrenForm", new {
Line 21:             ddtl = Model.DDTL,
Line 22:             listFamilies = Model.ListFamilies,
...
[JsCompilationException: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
   at ChildrenForm.jsx:6:8 -> import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';]
   JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.V8JsEngine.InnerExecute(String code, String documentName) +258
   React.ReactEnvironment.EnsureUserScriptsLoaded() +548
```

It seems like we cannot import files when using razor helper @Html.React and server side rendering.

How can I do an import and use React Hooks while server side rendering?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of having to import it, you can just use:

`const [ familyTiesId, setFamilyTiesId ] = React.useState(props.familyTiesId);`

Just call `useState` directly instead of importing.