# Is there a way to use React Hooks in a ReactJS.Net project

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, .net, reactjs.net

I have created an ASP.NET web Application(.NET framework) and have integrated React to it using ReactJS.NET package.

Now, when I try to use hooks in the functional components, it is not working.
Can someone share any github sources or links where **Hooks** were used in ReactJS.NET project

I have added the project in Github. Link: https://github.com/naveengorojanam/ReactPOC

in the project, the path to the JSX file is **ReactPOC/ReactPOC16/Scripts/JS/App.jsx**

```
function App() {
//const [temp, setTemp] = React.useState("hello");
return (
    <div>
        <h1>React functional component</h1>
        <button onClick={() => { window.alert('button clicked'); }}>click for alert</button>
    </div>
    )}
React.render(<App />, document.getElementById("reactdiv"));
```

I'm unable to run the temp hook from the App.jsx component.
Please let me know where i went wrong

If I uncomment the line `//const [temp, setTemp] = React.useState("hello");` , the project will not show any output

Comment: Here is a solution which worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57729900/how-can-i-use-react-hooks-with-reactjs-net

Comment: Hooks shouldn't be the issue, we will need to see your code to help.

Comment: Hello @KKKK , thanks for the tip.
do you have this sample project on github by any chance ?

Comment: @TR3 I have added the code repo in github. please go through it

Comment: What's the error message you are receiving?

Comment: @TR3 on the console, I'm getting the following error
App.jsx:7 Uncaught TypeError: React.useState is not a function or its return value is not iterable